# Material UI Datepicker to start from 1st day of next month

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I'm checking if I can change material-UI picker's default current date to first of next month but not able to find any. Would like to know if there is an option for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Set state inside the constructor `moment().add(1, 'M').startOf('month')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the input value prop to something like this:

```
var now = new Date(Date.now());
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState<Date | null>(
   new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 1)
);
```

Then set the value={selectedDate} on Mui Datepicker

Comment: Mark it as answer to help other devs :)